# Scrolling TiledMap in LibGDX

Tags: java, libgdx, 2d-games

I am currently using TiledMap, SimpleTiledAtlas(still can't figure out how to use pack files) and TileMapRenderer, following this tutorial: http://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/Tiles.

I don't know how to access the xyz of the map or how to change it in general. For initialization:

```
map = TiledLoader.createMap(Gdx.files.internal("tiles/tiles.tmx"));
    atlas = new SimpleTileAtlas(map, Gdx.files.internal("tiles/"));
    tileMapRenderer = new TileMapRenderer(map, atlas, 128, 128, 8, 8);
```

And for my rendering:

```
camera.zoom = 1.0f;
    camera.update();
    tileMapRenderer.render(camera);
    batch.begin();
    font.draw(batch, "FPS: " + Gdx.graphics.getFramesPerSecond(), 20, 20);
    tmp.set(0, 0, 0);
    camera.unproject(tmp);
    batch.end();
```

I've tried changing the tmp xyz but it doesn't seem to work. Also TileMapRenderer and TiledMap don't seem to have x and y fields.
Am I missing something or just too tired to notice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You move the camera, as opposed to the TiledMap or TileMapRenderer.

The <s>TiledMapTest</s> shows an example of how this works.

---

**EDIT**

The tile map api in LibGDX has changed since this answer was posted.

See [TiledMapDirectLoaderTest](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/TiledMapDirectLoaderTest.java) for an equivalent test using the new api.

Comment: Oh...thanks. There was a link to that in the tutorial, but it was broken. So (for future ppl reading this) you adjust the camera by changing the xyz of the position vector of the camera. Not really used to using vectors, so that's why I didn't think of it.

Comment: @Veger I updated the answer to reflect the link to the new test.